# How to dynamically send a chrome extension id to use with send_message in a webpage

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that is being called from a webpage via send_message.

```
function myFunction(Param1,Param2) {  
    var ExtensionId = "hoopakaeacgfagnjgnmkebfkaenincpb";
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(ExtensionId,{Param1:Param1,Param2:Param2});
}
```

The probelm is that I need to install the extension in multiple PCs and everytime the extension id is being changed. So I can't use a hardcoded extension id.

How can I dynamically retrive the extension id so that the code works on every PC that I use?

Comment: You can make the id permanent regardless of the machine, see [Obtaining Extension ID for development](//stackoverflow.com/a/23877974)

Comment: @wOxxOm, Is it safe that I generate the permanent extension id using OpenSSL,  and hardcoding this id in a webpage?

Comment: "Safe" is a vague word.

Comment: Sorry, will it be the right way of coding?